# layouts VertScrollBox dont show scroll bars after adding elements dynamically

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

i have a blank vertscrollbox at design time.
the vertscrollbox  have client align into the expander3 :

[image]

at run time i will add some button to vertscrollbox by this code:

```
  btnSelect := TButton.Create(VertScrollBox2);
  btnSelect.OnClick:= btnSelectCick;
  btnSelect.Parent := VertScrollBox2;
  btnSelect.Align := TAlignLayout.Scale;
  btnSelect.Position.X := cng*70;
  btnSelect.Position.Y := bng*70;
  btnSelect.Width := 60;
  btnSelect.Height := 60;
  btnSelect.text := 'Select'+bng.ToString+cng.ToString;
  btnSelect.name := 'Select'+bng.ToString+cng.ToString;
```

after 9 time run the above code it be like this:

you can see there is no scrollbar and some part of buttons is hiding under the border

[image]

how can i force vertscrollbox layout to show scrollbars? or update the alignment in runtime!?

Comment: Assuming that you have ShowScrollBars set to TRUE (the default) you could try  VertScrollBox2.InvalidateContentSize.

Comment: @Dsm ShowScrollBars is true and i tried InvalidateContentSize and not working for increase the scroll bars size!!

Comment: Please add the firemonkey tag.